# Importing bak database to business intelligence

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I want to import a database in .bak file to business intelligence in vs2013. But when I click "import from database" in analysis services (new project), I get an empty servers list, and localhost as a placeholder in a text field. Why is that so? How can I solve this?

I installed sql server 2014 and have an instance running.